# Is there a formula for fibonacci sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula for fibonacci sequence? If yes, how to derive it. I was told in class yesterday about this series, and I want to know if we can generalize it to any *n*.

If you don't know what the series is, It is a function such that $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ and $f(1)=1$ , $f(2)=1$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Comment: Just to point it out, googling "fibonacci number formula" gives, in the first result, a page on which this formula is given.

Comment: @Wojowu I saw that formula... I just wanted to know its derivation or a simpler formula if it exists.

Comment: Just a technicality, but this is not _a series_ but _a sequence_.

Comment: @AndyRock My link contains a derivation of this formula.

Comment: @Wojowu , Is that the derivation? Well, sorry, It was quite above my level. Thank you anyway for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the derivation, notice that this is defined as $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ so we form the auxiliary quadratic equation $k^2=k+1$. Solving this we find roots $\alpha= \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})$.

This means our solution will have the form $f(n)=A\alpha^n + B\beta^n$ for some constants $A,B$ which are determined using the initial conditions $f(1)=f(2)=1$. This gives the closed form expression above.

Comment: Isn't $\beta$ having a negative sign in the middle? Anyway, this derivation is much clearer than the one in wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed it now.

Comment: Let $M$ be the $2x2$ matrix whose top row is $(1,1)$ and lower row $ (0,1).$  For positive $n,$  the top row of $ M^n$ is $(F_{n+1}, F_n)$ and lower row $(F_n,F_{n-1})$. Proof by induction on $n$.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not seem an effective explanation. It is impossible to follow, unless one already knows the method. Why does the solution have to have the form $A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$? Why that polynomial?

Comment: Do we derive this formula with the tool from recurrence relations please? I found recurrence relations taught at discrete mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is

$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}⋅\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}⋅\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$.

You can prove this by induction or by converting to laplace domain.

Comment: The fibonacci series is all integers..How can this weird expression be the equation for it?

Comment: @AndyRock, use binomial formula on $(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2)^n$ and $(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2)^n$ separately. All irrational parts will cancel each other.

Comment: @Ennar Oh god!! that's right! How does that happen? Anyway, thanks for that.

Comment: I know how to find this with generating functions but not with Laplace domain. How is that done ?

Comment: @AndyRock Its fascinating how operations on irrational numbers always return natural numbers !

Comment: Observe that $S=\{s_1,s_2\}=\{(1\pm \sqrt 5)/2\}$ is the set of  solutions  of $x^2=x+1.$ So if $ y\in S$  then$ y^{n+1}=y^n+y^{n-1}.$  We can find $A,B$ with$ 0=A s_1^0+B s_2^0=A+B,$ and $1=A s_1+Bs_2.$  Then $ F_n=A s_1^n +B s_2^n$  for all $ n.$